# Simpsons episode in which Homer imagines Bart mounting his head on a wall

Tags: episode-identification, the-simpsons

Can't remember the episode, but I remember a scene in which Homer imagines Bart mounting his head on a wall (like a stag head), then Bart and Marge are shown sitting and drinking. Marge is wearing a dress, while Bart is wearing a suit or a fancy bathrobe.

Comment: That'll be one of the Treehouse of Horror episodes.

Comment: @user169388 - I edited your description in an attempt to clarify what I think you were getting at. If I got anything wrong, please edit the question yourself to fix it.

Comment: @Valorum I remember the episode, and it doesn't have anything sci-fi nor fantasy about it (see the answer, which is the correct one)

Comment: @Clockwork - Aye. If OP confirms it, we can close this question :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about science fiction nor fantasy

Answer (score 7):

According to the [wiki](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Tennis_the_Menace) that would be the episode "Tennis the Menace" (Season 12 Episode 12).

> The [tennis] court is very popular with the residents, who also insulting Homer and Marge for losing all the time due to Homer's absent-mindedness. Marge pleads with Homer to take the games seriously; however, Homer is too oblivious to see how bad he is in tennis. Homer tries to please Marge by entering Krusty's celebrity tournament, the "Krusty Kharity Klassic". Homer is a hopeless tennis player, so Marge "dumps" him and enters with Bart as her new partner. Homer is outraged that he was abandoned for his ten year old son. He has a nightmare where Bart and Marge are married and he is a wall trophy, after being shot at a guillotine factory.

Comment: I can confirm this. It was the episode in which Homer felt like he was getting replaced by his own son, because he didn't know how to play.